# Error API Microsoft Graph integrated with MISP

Tags: api, graph

I'm writing this email after the maintainer of the MISP repository answered a question asked by me. I'm integrating MISP with Sentinel using Microsoft Graph API and I came across the error in the image below. According to MISP support, the error is related to the script not being prepared to page and receive the responses in full, as the MISP database that I am importing is very large, it generates an error in the execution of time out. As per MISP support, you will need to edit this file: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/security-api-olutions/blob/master/Samples/MISP/script.py and change the _get_events method to iterate over the responses.

[image]

The steps were performed according to the github documentation.

Comment: Welcome! Please [edit] to convert your images of text into actual text. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) for why.

Comment: Is this the answer to the question? If you want to self-answer, put the answer in an _answer_ post. See [ask] and [answer]. It's fine and even encouraged to self-answer questions as long as the both the question and answer stand alone as high-quality questions and answers.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.